# iPhone 5S and iPad 4

Tags: storage

I purchased 20 GB extra of storage for my iPad and iPhone on iCloud. But my devices say they are still full. How do I get the storage to show up so I can download an update, apps etc.?

Comment: You bought extra cloud storage, not extra phone/pad memory [which is not possible]. The two are utterly unrelated. You need to transfer some data to a computer, or delete it, to free up extra space on the devices.

Comment: @Tetsujin maybe make your comment an answer to make it canonical? I've seen more than a few this.

Answer (score 2):

You bought extra cloud storage, not extra phone/pad memory [which is not possible].
The two are utterly unrelated.

You need to transfer some data to a computer, or delete it, to free up extra space on the devices.